# Why I an getting undefined user disconnected socket.io

Tags: socket.io, chat

I am using socket.io to build chat system, i m using this

```
io.on('connection', function( socket ){
     socket.on('adduser', function( uname ){
        socket.username = uname;
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function( ) {
        console.log( socket.username + " disconnected");
    });
});
```

but its shows **undefined disconnected**.

Where's the error in this code??

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `disconnect` message BEFORE you get a `adduser` message on that particular socket, then the `socket.username` property will not be set and you will see `undefined disconnected` in the console.

So, apparently the client isn't sending the adduser message before a disconnect.  We could help further if we could see the client code.  Or, you can just change your disconnect logging to something like this:

```
io.on('connection', function( socket ){
     socket.on('adduser', function( uname ){
        socket.username = uname;
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function( ) {
        if (socket.username) {
            console.log( socket.username + " disconnected");
        } else {
            console.log('socket disconnected before username set');
        }
    });
});
```